# Json single line is too long

Tags: json, format

I have a super long value for a key in a json file. Is there any way to format this single line into multiple lines for easier reading? Thank you so much!

"transforms.route.topic.expression":"if (value.source.table == 'test_item') {'rec.test_item'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 0){'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel0'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 1) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel1'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 2) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel2'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 3) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel3'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 4) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel4'} else null"

```
"transforms.route.topic.expression":"if (value.source.table == 'test_item') {'rec.test_item'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 0){'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel0'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 1) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel1'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 2) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel2'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 3) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel3'} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 4) {'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel4'} else null"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be split into lines in an array, which can be joined together again later, e.g.:

```json
"transforms.route.topic.expression": [
  "if (value.source.table == 'test_item') {'",
  "rec.test_item'",
  "} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 0){",
  "'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel0'",
  "} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 1) {",
  "'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel1'",
  "} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 2) {",
  "'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel2'",
  "} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 3) {",
  "'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel3'",
  "} else if (value.after != null && value.after.item_channel == 4) {",
  "'rec.test_item.order_item.item_channel4'",
  "} else null"
]
```

If using e.g. JavaScript, then join like this:

```js
json["transforms.route.topic.expression"] = json["transforms.route.topic.expression"].join("");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I would like to use this json file directly without any language compiling later? I will use a post request in the CLI with this json file directly. Thank you again.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible, as the CLI wouldn't know that the content of the JSON file continues on the next line.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!